# GitWeb : Cloning doesn't succeed

Tags: git, centos, gitweb

I just setup a gitweb server on a centos 7 machine, but when I'm trying to clone, he ask me a password ? How can I change the password on the server, because I never set one...

```
$ git clone git@xxx.xxx.x.xx:gitolite-admin.git

  Cloning into 'gitolite-admin'...
  git@xxx.xxx.x.xx's password: 
  Permission denied, please try again.
```

**Edit**

I force change the git user password on the serveur and it's ok now.

But I got this :

```
fatal: 'testing.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

But if i go on the url (http://xxx.xxx.x.xx/gitweb/) he see them all :

[image]

Comment: Seems like you are trying to connect to your git-repo with ssh. Does a user named 'git' exists on your server? If so, try to use the password of the user git

Comment: Did you configure the required SSH keys?

Comment: Did you initialised the repo with --bare ?

Comment: Yep, re-edit : I can access to him if i clone with this url : git clone git@xxx.xxx.x.xx:repositorie/gitolite-admin.git

But in my gitolite-suexec-wrapper.sh, the GIT_PROJECT_ROOT is set tom /home/git/repositories so why do I have to specify the folder ? I will try to change the http home.

Comment: Did changing the GIT_PROJECT_ROOT to the folder of your repo worked?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I still have to specify...

Comment: Are you building the CGI Script yourself? According to the docs: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-GitWeb you always have to spefify the root-folder of your project...

Answer (score 0):

According to what you wrote in command line:

---

I can suggest that you are trying to connect to user called git which have password set-up at the beginning stage.

---

Your connection is through ssd; can you try to connect over ssh-dss and update us.

Also consider having look on this website as it might be helpful:
[gitweb-simple-usage-on-centos-7][1]http://frederic-wou.net/gitweb-simple-usage-on-centos-7-2/